# Android register key file in KeyStore

Tags: java, android, ssl

I want to access an api which uses TLS. I tested this in plain java on my computer. To access the api I had to generate key/certificate and upload TLS Certificate in pem format to that api on their website https://developer-sandbox.rabobank.nl/application/... I then added the key I generated to keystore like this:

```java
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/key/key.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "secret");
```

Now I want to access the api from my android app. My question is how I register that key to `keyStore`(android's keystore is also fine) and where would I put the key file? When I send requests from the app without doing anything with the key, I get a 404 not found error.

What I could find about keys was mostly about a key as a `String` in code.